# Using higher timeframe data as a condition for entry

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I have created a strategy that uses (as part of it) higher timeframe emas and smmas as a condition for entry. I have managed to get them to plot on the chart but when I add them to the indicator it fails to plot the buy and sell signals but doesn't throw up any errors. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

PS - I am new to coding so my layout isn't great, so much so that I'm getting an error message when I try to paste it in here.

```
Code access from - https://pastebin.com/7gN63byy
```